# How to install an SQLSRV extension to php XAMPP

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to install a SQLSRV extension. My PHP version is 7.2 (XAMPP 3.2.2) and I use windows 10. I downloaded the .dll from here: https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases. Then I unpacked it to the `xampp/php/ext` folder [image]

After that I opened the `php.ini` and added this extension:

1. **extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts**
2. **extension=php_sqlsrv_72_nts**

Next I restarted the Apache server.

Unfortunately when I open the phpinfo website I don't see the extension. Also when I open the XAMPP shell and type **php** I'm getting an error.

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts'
>   (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts (Module was not found.)

My extension_dir in php.ini is set to `extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"`.

Architecture is x86.

What did I do wrong?

**EDIT:**
I've changed the nts to ts files and now its working.

Answer (score 6):

worked for me by telling in the PHP.ini file in this way:

```
extension=mysql
extension=sqlsrv
extension=pdo_sqlsrv
```

so, you have to remove "php_" and ".dll"

Comment: While this may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer worked for me. I didn't see pdo_sqlsrv on phpinfo() before applying what this answer says.

Comment: extension=pdo_sqlsrv - you only need this, but have in mind version of php, and dll. I did all steps with newest php and it didn't work. Used a litle bit older and all was ok. Check phpinfo to for sqlsrv entry, becouse dll was loading ok but not working.

Comment: I am getting error in shel `Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysql' (tried: G:\xampp\php\ext\mysql (The specified module could not be found.), G:\xampp\php\ext\php_mysql.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv' (tried: G:\xampp\php\ext\sqlsrv (The specified module could not be found.), G:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: `Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv' (tried: G:\xampp\php\ext\sqlsrv (The specified module could not be found.), G:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv' (tried: G:\xampp\php\ext\pdo_sqlsrv (The specified module could not be found.), G:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: `Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv' (tried: G:\xampp\php\ext\pdo_sqlsrv (The specified module could not be found.), G:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0`

Answer (score 5):

- Please Make sure the extension and php.ini file is in same path.  and
  you running same php.exe file.
- If there is no path issue then you can try it:

**Remove** the

> **php_**

prefix from your php.ini file. because php automatically searching with the name of file with the prefix: ***php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll***
Example: if you register the dll file as:

> pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86

then php will search the dll file as:

> php_php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll